# Android-Iconics - how to set icon programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using the [Android-Iconics](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics) library to have sharp and beautiful icons. 
Declaring the icons in the XML layout files like this works fine:

```
<com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="7dp"
            app:iiv_color="@color/colorDarkGrey"
            app:iiv_icon="gmd-send" />
```

I would like to switch the icon programmatically, unfortunately this does NOT work:

```
btn_send.setIcon("gmd-voicemail");
```

But using the same String "gmd-voicemail" as value for the field `app:iiv_icon` in the xml layout is working.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the solution is to NOT declare the field `app:iiv_icon="gmd-send"` in the first place. Otherwise it seems it can not be overwritten.